# How to copy text form one Jtextarea to another jtextarea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, documentlistener

I have to copy the contents of a jtextarea to another jtextarea.How can it be done.I have done the following:But this program is writing the text form one jtext area to another character by character. I want it to copy it when the user hits the enter key(carage returm.how do i do it? Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class JtextareaTest {

    static JTextComponent jtextArea1;
    static JTextArea jtextArea2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        jtextArea1 = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        jtextArea2 = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        jtextArea1.setEditable(true);
        jtextArea2.setEditable(true);
        MyDocListen listener = new MyDocListen();
        jtextArea1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTextArea");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Create and set up the content pane.
        Container newContentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
        jpanel.add(jtextArea1);
        jpanel.add(jtextArea2);
        newContentPane.add(jpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyDocListen implements DocumentListener {

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        getText();

    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    }

    public void getText() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String str = JtextareaTest.jtextArea1.getText();
        sb.append(str);
        JtextareaTest.jtextArea2.setText(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: ENTER key is implemented as a new line in JTextArea, you would need to remove built in KeyBindings, but then is question how do you to create a new line, don't to confuse an users

Comment: You are creating unnecessary StringBuffer. Strings are immutable so you can assign it directly to jtextArea2 from jtextArea1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DocumentListener is used for detecting changes to a text document. You want to use it when you want something to happen every time the text changes.

You said that you want something to happen every time the user pushes the enter key. Because of this, as @camickr rightfully pointed out, you should consider using a [Key Binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead. Read up on the doc page, as that is the most correct way to handle hot keys in a JComponent.

The quick-and-dirty way to do it would be to use a [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) instead, which listens for key presses at a low level. Note that this is not the most correct way to do it, and that it may make your code difficult to maintain.

If you do wish to use a KeyListener, then do the following: change your MyDocListen class to some other class that implements KeyListener, and implement KeyListener.keyTyped() to check if it was the enter key that was pushed, and if it was, call getText():

```
class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener {
    public void getText()
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String str = JtextareaTest.jtextArea1.getText();
        sb.append(str);
        JtextareaTest.jtextArea2.setText(sb.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            getText();
        }
    }
}
```

Then just change the line

```
MyDocListen listener= new MyDocListen();
```

to

```
MyKeyListener listener = new MyKeyListener();
```

and be sure to add the KeyListener to the JTextArea itself, not its document. To do this, replace this line:

```
jtextArea1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);
```

with this:

```
jtextArea1.addKeyListener(listener);
```

and that should fix your problem.

Comment: @star, ` you should consider using a KeyListener instead,` - no you should not. You SHOULD be [using Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) as has already been mentioned by mKorbel. Also, the default behaviour for a JTextArea is to add a newline to the text area. If you add this functionality then how is the user ever going to add a newline to the text area? If you don't need new lines, then you should be using a JTextField and then just add an ActionListenr to the text field which will be invoked when Enter is pressed.

Comment: @camickr I retract my previous comment; I'm an idiot, misread the page, and attempted to disprove you by showing you your own point.

I will edit this answer to include your point.

Comment: I will be using the above code for communicating between two users in a communicator.So here do i need to use key bindings or keylistener?The text will be displayed in the communicator text areas

Answer (score 0):

or use this->

```
private void jButtonKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {     
    char c == evt.getKeyChar();
    if(c==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
    yoursecondtextarea.setText(yourfirsttextarea.getText());
    }
}
```